# How to remove a single character from the filename of a list of files in a folder using DOS command?

Tags: dos

I have a list of files like these:
icone1.gif
icone2.gif
icone1.gif
icone11.gif
icone12.gif
icone13.gif
icone14.gif
icone15.gif

I want to remove 'e' from it so they will icon1.gif, icon2.gif and so on...

I tried this from the DOS Command Prompt:

```
ren icone*.gif icon*.gif
```

Didn't work.

Comment: Obligatory "did you mean batch or are you literally using MS-DOS because those aren't the same thing" comment.

Comment: I don't think there's a good way to do this from a DOS command prompt-- If the OS has powershell there's some hope.. otherwise your best bet might be to build a batch file that explicitly renames each file.

Comment: The reason that doesnt work is because you are saying for each file starting with icone rename it to icon and the remainder of the filename.gif (which includes the e) It's a pain and I don't think you can get around it with just one line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a batch file in the folder by typing "notepad go.bat" at the command prompt and hitting enter and drop this in then save and exit notepad:

```
for %%i in ("*.gif") do (set fname=%%i) & call :rename
goto :eof
:rename
::Cuts off 1st five chars, then appends Icon and the remaining chars
ren "%fname%" "Icon%fname:~5%"
goto :eof
```

Double click the batch file in windows or from the command prompt type go and press enter

Answer (score 1):

See [How does the Windows RENAME (REN) command interpret wildcards?](https://superuser.com/q/475874/109090) for rules that can explain why your command does not work.

Assuming all your file names have a digit after "icone" (really only care that you never have another "e" following "icone"), then the following one liner will work from the command line.

```
for /f "tokens=1* delims=eE" %A in ('dir /b icone*.gif') do @ren "%Ae%B" "%A%B"
```

Double up the percents if you put the command within a batch script.

For a really simple and robust solution, use my [JREN.BAT regular expression renaming utility](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=6081), pure script (hybrid JScript/batch) that runs natively on any Windows machine from XP onward.

```
jren "^(icon)e(.*\.jpg)" "$1$2" /i
```